# Cannot serialize an object of class Post into BSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, bson

I have in model **post.rb**:

```
class Post
 include Mongoid::Document
 attr_accessible :content, :original_post
end
```

in create action in **posts_controller.rb**:

```
def create
 @post = Post.new(params[:post])
 @post.original_post = @post
 @post.save
end
```

I want to know that this post is the original because I will do copy of this post and I will have more post with the same features.

However when I try create the post, I get the error:

**BSON::InvalidDocument (Cannot serialize an object of class Post into BSON.):**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to serialize empty Post, like:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
@post.save
```

May be the problem is that `@post` contains itself as variable. And it cannot be serialized to json (bson).

Comment: Thank you but I need save `@post.original_post = @post`. That works fine, but I need save in `@post.original_post` the object @post. How can I do it?

Comment: If I put `@post.original_post = @post.id` I don't get error. But If I put `@post.original_post` and I get `=> BSON::ObjectId('4f2ef01b1d41c82f1f000057')` but I dont get the params...

Comment: @hyperrjas Try to add `has_one: original_post`

Comment: This it does not works :(. I get error in my model with `has_one :original_post`. original_post its an attribute that belongs to model/object Post. It's not a model...

Comment: I have put in model Post `has_one :post belongs_to :post` and now create an attribute `post_id:` and it does works fine :D. I don't know if this is correct. How can change the attribute name to e.g. `original_post` for better understanding in the code?